# Powershell: How can I pull AD user data by matching their 'departmentnumber' to a department numbers list provided in a CSV file?

Tags: powershell, active-directory

So I've been given a huge list of locations and asked to produce a report of all users that reside in these locations. Locations are ID'ed by numbers so one location may be 1 and another may be 76 and so on and so forth. The list also lists some locations more than once. The header used for this list of locations is "LocationID" The AD attribute I'm matching to these numbers is DepartmentNumber. So far I've got the following:

```
#Importing list of locations

$LocationData = Import-Csv "C:\Users\xxxx\xxxx\Desktop\LocationID.csv"

#Revising list of locations to only utilize single instances of each location

$LocationID = $LocationData | Select-Object LocationID -Unique

#Searching AD for each user that has a matching department to those held in $LocationID

Foreach ($Branch in $LocationID) {

$UserList = Get-ADUser -filter {departmentNumber -eq $($Branch.LocationID)} -Property * -SearchBase 'OU=xxxx,DC=xxxx,DC=xxxx,DC=xxxx' -server xxxxxxxx | Select-Object Name,Mail,Title,Manager,DepartmentNumber
    
}
```

The issue I'm running into is that when attempting to run the foreach loop I am getting the following error:

```
Get-ADUser : Cannot process argument because the value of argument "path" is not valid. Change the value of the "path" argument and run the operation again.
At line:3 char:13
+ $UserList = Get-ADUser -filter {departmentNumber -eq $($Branch.Locati ...
+             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Get-ADUser], PSArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ActiveDirectoryCmdlet:System.Management.Automation.PSArgumentException,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.GetADUser
```

Would anyone happen to know what's causing this error? Or what I may be doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue with your code is the use of a script block in the `-Filter` parameter, even though this can work in certain situations it will fail in this particular case where you want to expand the value of the property of an object. Your filter should look like this to work properly:

```bash
-Filter "departmentNumber -eq '$($Branch.LocationID)'"
```

As an improvement for your code, instead of querying AD per each `LocationID` in your CSV, what you can do instead is construct a filter to query AD only once:

```bash
$filter = '(|'
Import-Csv 'C:\Users\xxxx\xxxx\Desktop\LocationID.csv' |
    Select-Object LocationId -Unique |
    ForEach-Object { $filter += '(departmentNumber={0})' -f $_.LocationID }
$filter += ')'

$getADUserSplat = @{
    LDAPFilter = $filter
    Properties = 'Name', 'Mail', 'Title', 'Manager', 'DepartmentNumber'
    SearchBase = 'OU=xxxx,DC=xxxx,DC=xxxx,DC=xxxx'
    Server     = 'xxxxxxxx'
}

Get-ADUser @getADUserSplat |
    Select-Object $getADUserSplat['Properties'] |
    Export-Csv path\to\export.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Thank you for the advice! Looks like that corrected my issue but due to the size of the list of locations it is taking a very long time to complete. Would your method also reduce the time it takes for the code to run?

Comment: @ElijahRobinson yes, I exclusively provided that coded because it will be faster

Comment: Awesome. My last question then is will I be able to export these results to a csv without issues?

Comment: yeah just need to pipe `Export-Csv...` after the `Select-Object` statement @ElijahRobinson

Comment: So I tried that prior to asking and it exports to a csv but the content of the csv is no longer readable. The csv contains random letters and numbers instead of the output displayed in powershell.

Comment: @ElijahRobinson are you sure you're copying exactly the code as I'm showing it in the answer? sounds like you have used `Format-Table`. See the edit on my answer, it should look exactly as shown here

Comment: Ah guilty. I did add a FT just to format the output. Is that not something that I can do here?

Comment: @ElijahRobinson `FT` and `FL` and `FW` are exclusively for displaying output to the console in a certain way, they're not meant to be used on exporting cmdlets.

Comment: I did not know that. Is there a method I could use instead to export the output to a csv in a format that would resemble the FT format? (Column headers, etc)

Comment: @ElijahRobinson just dont use `FT`, `Export-CSv` will already handle the formatting so that you can open the exported document with Excel just fine..